# Windows complaining about file length when the value is under the limit

Tags: windows, visual-studio, azure

I can't find anything online about this because searching for `Windows is lying` doesn't really help me :-)

In my visual studio project I have an import relating to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets` and the full path is

> (MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets

This relates to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets

which for me is 153 characters but windows in complaining that that is too long and the limit is 260.

Error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Windows
>   Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(1061,5): error : The
>   specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified
>   file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name
>   must be less than 248 characters.

I have fixed this by storing the DLL in the repository but I'd like to know whats going on here and if there is a better fix?

Using GitLab CI and Powershell with MSBuild if that means anything.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Storing the DLL in the repository returns the same issue so maybe this is a problem with `Windows Azure Tools`?

Comment: You should instead search for `microsoft.windowsazure.targets path too long`.

Comment: Very true. Thanks. It was the `<ServiceOutputDirectory>C:\Azure\</ServiceOutputDirectory>` answer that worked. Nobody (or I can't find it) explains why this is happening when the file length isn't "too long".